# Displaying image from url, ImageView does not work, WebView does

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

I have  an `ImageView` like this

```
 <ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageFromUrl"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
   android:adjustViewBounds="true"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

and I have to display an image from an address I get from a webservice during runtime.

Note that the dimensions of the image is quite large (249x2902) but the size of the file is very small, about 32k.

I tried

```
 URL url = new URL(urlToImage);
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 connection.setDoInput(true);
 connection.connect();
 InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
 Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
 imageFromUrl.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

and this does not seem to render the image, it's just white.

I also tired

```
imageFromUrl.setImageURI(Uri.parse(urlToImage));
```

and that does not work either, the screen is white.

But if i use a `WebView` and do

```
webView.loadUrl(urlToImage);
```

it loads fine.

What gives? Why does `ImageView` not work?

I'm testing on a Galaxy Tab 2 where it is not working. If I try it on the emulator, everything is fine, ImageView works.

Comment: a WebView already has it's own threading to do network traffic off the UI thread.  Loading the image yourself via HttpURLConnection or even ImageFromURI is doing network activity on the UI thread.  It ought to give you an exception doing networking on the UI thread

Comment: @Martin the case where I use HttpURLConnection, I did use AsyncTask to get the bitmap in doInBackground() and I used it's onPostExecute() which is on the ui thread to set the bitmap and got no exceptions. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here:

First, the size in Kbs doesn't mean it will not make the app crash because of the way android handle images, internally in the heap the file will take the memory of width * height * 4Bytes, a file of 1Kb size with huge dimensions could easily become several MBs, in order to download and handle big size files you should stick to the android best practices shown in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), they provide a mechanism to check ImageBounds without loading it, and once calculated load the proper image size that fits whatever area you want.

Second, according to the code you are showing seems like you are downloading the image in the main UI thread, take on count that this action is prohibited in the latest android versions, throwing an Exception for using network calls in the main Thread. For a better response please post the logcat exception if any... but no matter what, you should never directly load such a big size image, read the link provided for further information

Hope this Helps.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the response. Regarding your second point, I am using an AsyncTask's doInBackground to get the Bitmap and setting it to the control in onPostExecute() and I don't get any exceptions. I didn't mention that for brevity.

Comment: Your first point is very interesting, I'm looking into it now.

Comment: I experimented with the  `options.inSampleSize` mentioned in your linked documentation. If I set it to 2 or greater, it works but the image is scaled down to a point where the text in the image is not legible. If i set it to 1 (default) it does not load. so is this a memory issue then ?